# Merge Sort implementation outputs wrong results

Tags: c++14, mergesort

I am trying to implement Merge Sort in C++ 14. I've written the full code and proof-read it multiple times for logical faults but can't find any. But the code outputs a wrong sorted array that sometimes even contains duplicate elements and/or elements that were never input to the array in the first place.

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
void merge_sort(vector<int>&, int, int);
void print_vector(vector<int>&);
void merge(vector<int>&, int, int, int);

int main() {
    int arr_len = 0;
    cout << "Enter the length of the array to be sorted: " << endl;
    cin >> arr_len;

    vector<int> arr(arr_len);

    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
        int buff;
        cin >> buff;
        arr[i] = buff;
    }

    cout << "The elements entered in the unsorted vector are: " << endl;
    print_vector(arr);

    merge_sort(arr, 0, arr_len - 1);

    cout << "After Merge sorting, the elements in the vector are: " << endl;
    print_vector(arr);

    return 0;
}

void print_vector(vector<int>& arr) {
    for (auto itr = arr.begin(); itr != arr.end(); ++itr) {
        cout << *itr << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void merge_sort(vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;           // used this instead of (low + high) / 2 to avoid overflow problems
        merge_sort(arr, low, mid);                  // recursive call to merge_sort with high = mid's updated value
        merge_sort(arr, mid + 1, high);
        merge(arr, low, mid, high);                 // call to merge to sort and merge the fragmented arrays.
    }
}

void merge(vector<int>& arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int l_arr_len = mid - low + 1;
    int r_arr_len = high - mid;
    vector<int> l_arr(l_arr_len);
    vector<int> r_arr(r_arr_len);

    for (int i = 0; i < l_arr_len; i++) {        // initialise elements of temp_arr1 (l_arr) to 0.
        l_arr[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r_arr_len; i++) {        // initialise elements of temp_arr2 (r_arr) to 0.   
        r_arr[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l_arr_len; i++) {        // transfer elements from arr to l_arr, upto length of the fragmented l_arr.
        l_arr[i] = arr[low + i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < r_arr_len; i++) {        // transfer remaining elements from arr to r_arr, upto length of the fragmented r_arr.
        r_arr[i] = arr[mid + 1 + i];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < l_arr_len && j < r_arr_len) {            // compare and replace elements in the mother array arr
        if (l_arr[i] <= r_arr[j]) {                      // smallest element goes first
            arr[k++] = l_arr[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = r_arr[j++];
        }
    }

    while (i < l_arr_len) {                  // write remaining elements in the left_arr fragment to mother array arr
        arr[k++] = l_arr[i++];
    }

    while (j < r_arr_len) {                  // write remaining elements in the left_arr fragment to mother array arr
        arr[k++] = r_arr[j++];
    }
}
```

For an input array of elements `[2, 9, 4, 5, 7]`, the correct sorted result would have been: `[2, 4, 5, 7, 9]`.

But my implementation outputs: `[5, 5, 7, 7, 9]`. I don't understand where the duplicate elements came from and why they replaced the original elements. While I've tried to add comments to almost statement out there for ease of access of the SO community, some of those may be redundant.

Since I'm out of my wits, please help me correct my code. You can point out what's wrong & where if that's what's convenient.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: try debugging your merge when low is not 0

Comment: I can confirm that the fix suggested by Kenny Ostrom's comment will work.

Comment: Yes, I have just confirmed the fix. I would have marked your answer to be selected but you appear to have deleted your post. Thanks anyways for the help. In my answer I'll credit both @KennyOstrom and you.

Comment: @GourabIX - Kenny Ostrom commented probably while I was editing my answer (it's undeleted now).  You might consider changing high to be a non-inclusive index, so that the initial call parameters are: {arr, 0, arr.size() }. This is more common for top down merge sort, while high = arr.size()-1 is more common for quicksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the merge function, initialize k to low, not zero:

```
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = low;
```

I just noticed Kenny Ostrom's comment is probably about making this change.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was found by others, `k` must be initialized to `low` instead of `0`.

There are more issues you should look at:

- the proper type for array index values and sizes is `size_t`, not `int`, which might have a much smaller range.
- passing the index of the last element instead of the excluded upper bound produces cumbersome code with index adjustments.
- there is no need to initialize the temporary vectors, you should just copy the contents, or better construct them from an array slice.
- `print_vector` should take a `const` reference.

Here is modified version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
void merge_sort(vector<int>&, size_t, size_t);
void merge(vector<int>&, size_t, size_t, size_t);
void print_vector(const vector<int>&);

int main() {
    size_t arr_len = 0;
    cout << "Enter the length of the array to be sorted: " << endl;
    cin >> arr_len;

    vector<int> arr(arr_len);

    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: " << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "The elements entered in the unsorted vector are: " << endl;
    print_vector(arr);

    merge_sort(arr, 0, arr_len);

    cout << "After Merge sorting, the elements in the vector are: " << endl;
    print_vector(arr);

    return 0;
}

void print_vector(const vector<int>& arr) {
    for (auto itr = arr.begin(); itr != arr.end(); ++itr) {
        cout << *itr << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void merge_sort(vector<int>& arr, size_t low, size_t high) {
    if (high - low > 1) {
        size_t mid = low + (high - low) / 2;    // used this instead of (low + high) / 2 to avoid overflow problems
        merge_sort(arr, low, mid);              // recursive call to merge_sort with high = mid's updated value
        merge_sort(arr, mid, high);
        merge(arr, low, mid, high);             // call to merge to sort and merge the fragmented arrays.
    }
}

void merge(vector<int>& arr, size_t low, size_t mid, size_t high) {
    size_t l_arr_len = mid - low;
    size_t r_arr_len = high - mid;
    vector<int> l_arr(l_arr_len);
    vector<int> r_arr(r_arr_len);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < l_arr_len; i++) {    // transfer elements from arr to l_arr, upto length of the fragmented l_arr.
        l_arr[i] = arr[low + i];
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r_arr_len; i++) {    // transfer remaining elements from arr to r_arr, upto length of the fragmented r_arr.
        r_arr[i] = arr[mid + i];
    }

    size_t i = 0, j = 0, k = low;
    while (i < l_arr_len && j < r_arr_len) {    // compare and replace elements in the mother array arr
        if (l_arr[i] <= r_arr[j]) {             // smallest element goes first
            arr[k++] = l_arr[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = r_arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < l_arr_len) {                  // write remaining elements in the left_arr fragment to mother array arr
        arr[k++] = l_arr[i++];
    }
    while (j < r_arr_len) {                  // write remaining elements in the left_arr fragment to mother array arr
        arr[k++] = r_arr[j++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for including the detailed code-review, and for adding the full modified code as well. However, could you elaborate a bit about the 2nd bullet point that you added?

Comment: @GourabIX: regarding the comment about index values: in your version, you pass the index of the last included element in the slice to be sorted. Many schoolbooks show examples with this approach, but for languages with 0 based array indices, such as C, java, javascript, python, etc. it is more idiomatic to pass the index of the first excluded element. This simplifies the code as you can see from my answer and avoids `-1` adjustments in many places, some of which might be inappropriate or just forgotten.

Comment: @GourabIX: another advantage of this convention is it allows for empty slices, which `low == high` and makes the slice length trivially computed as `high - low`.

Comment: Gotcha. That's a nice handy shortcut. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my code, specifically in the `void merge(...)` function I initialised the variable `k` to `0`. This variable `k` is supposed to track where in the mother array `arr` the sorted element is placed, depending on its value.

What that resulted in was that no matter which fragment of the mother array `arr` it is, when sorting and merging elements from the different array fragments together, `k` being hard-coded to `0`, the first (already sorted) element of `arr` was being replaced by the next element from any of the array fragments that satisfied the condition. So the array would be filled up eventually, and the program will exit correctly, but not before injecting duplicates in the partially sorted array, the duplicates coming from the replacement of `arr[k++]` element by the either of the array fragments: `l_arr` or `r_arr`. Of course, this is wrong according to the principle of merge sort as the pattern of merging of the array elements is to be maintained. It's difficult to visualise this probably, so here's a representation of the Merge Sort for reference:

[image: Merge Sort Schematic Representation. Notice the arrows and how it all comes together.]

So, here's the fix: `k` should be initialised to `low` **instead of** `0`. That way, the pattern of Merge Sort is maintained, the appropriate elements from the appropriate fragments are combined together recursively to form the sorted array.

This fix was suggested by [Kenny Ostrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766544/kenny-ostrom) and [rcgldr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282056/rcgldr). Thanks a lot to them both!